# How can I find JETTY_HOME on windows

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

I'm trying to install a keystore onto my local Jetty server from Eclipse.  The instructions I found [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jetty/jetty-ssl-configuration-example/) say I need to go to JETTY_HOME to install my new keystore, but I can't figure out where that is.  I can run Jetty from my Maven projet in Eclipse.  Is there some way I can get Eclipse to tell me the JETTY_HOME?

Comment: JETTY_HOME implies the path where jetty is installed and defined as JETTY_HOME on your environment variables.

Too see the varible (path of the directory); based on your OS run `echo %JETTY_HOME%` for Windows; or `echo $JETTY_HOME` for Unix on your command line / terminal.
Check if it prints the path of the directory, if it prints nothing then you should manually define it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions probably don't even assume JETTY_HOME has been set as an environment value. It's just a a way to talk about the directory where *you* have installed jetty.

Answer (score 0):

this variables are stored as system environment variables.
open a cmd and type

```
echo %JETTY_HOME%
```

to see where it points to